# how to define a web3 contract type in typescript

Tags: web3js

So I am trying to define a type of web3 contract with typescript. We know that a web3 contract is defined in the form that

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)
```

My question is that How to define a type of such contract so that the following code is possible

```
function myFunction(someContract: contract){...}
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: What would be the intended usage? and why do you want to define a contract like that?

Comment: I have figured out. It turns out that I can simply import such type from web3 source code.

Comment: I would be nice if you can write what changes were made so the question can be mark as answered.

Comment: You can use [Typechain](https://github.com/dethcrypto/TypeChain) to generate TypeScript bindings for your Ethereum smart contracts. If you use my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template), you don't even have to configure Typechain yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this can be easily done by import type Contract from the source code of web3.

Comment: Can you add a little snippet how the code looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can import types from the actual modules instead of 'web3'...

```
import type {Eth} from 'web3-eth';
import type {Contract} from 'web3-eth-contract';
import type {AbiItem} from 'web3-utils';

const eth: Eth = web3.eth;
const contract: Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi as AbiItem[], '...');
```